# Dragging chart with brush selection

Tags: d3.js, brush

The problem is the following, I have a chart and brush tool over the chart. The issue is that there is a zoom feature, which should work in a combination with brush. so the user case is that he selects some range with brush like 30% of the chart and during zoom brush selection must scale(it works), and if the scale is more than 1, he must be able to drag the chart with brush selection, but now brush works with chart panning. Is it possible to implement?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108890/d3-zoom-and-brush-working-at-the-same-time)?

Comment: Yes, @LarsKotthoff, in that question the brush is removed at all with d3.select('.brush').remove(); on the last line, but in my question user must be able to drag chart with brush selection.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirements. When do you want to drag, and when do you want a mouse move while clicked to modify the brush?

Comment: Sorry for this - there is a button - zoom toggle, so in this zoom mode brush should be visible and draggable but not responding drag event(brush selection). now in zoom mode graph is zooming and panning but brush also responses, i.e. on graph panning new brush selection fired, but brush selection should only drag with the chart

Comment: So in zoom mode you want both to be working? How do you determine whether a mouse click move is to drag the graph or change the brush?

Comment: not exactly, in zoom mode the brush selection should be visible and moving with graph on drag, but shouldn't change, i.e. in zoom mode brush should be just visible and not respond to mouse events, otherwise user will lose its selection. So now graph is dragging and brush is updating during drag, should be only dragging with visible brush selection. problem is close to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036836/disable-clearing-of-d3-js-brush

Comment: Could you show us the code you have that tries to do this?